# cms pages and block is not loading in backend

Tags: javascript, cms, magento2.2.2, cms-block, cms-pages

CMS pages and blocks won't load in the backend. It keeps loading and loading without not showing any pages or blocks. I reindex, compile, clear cache... But nothing changed. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: how about running upgrade command and redeploying static contents? did you try?

Comment: Do you have .htaccess in your pub?

Comment: yes I tried upgrade and deploy comman twice but doesn't help me. I have the .htaccess file in pub

Comment: Due to this console error everywhere in backend facing same issue order / customer listing etc.. is also not loading.. @JeevaChezhiyan

Comment: Are you using any third party module or overrided any files in admin?

Comment: pub/static/frontend/Magento/sss/en_US/js-translation.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
require.js:141 Uncaught Error: http://abc.in/pub/static/frontend/Magento/sss/en_US/js-translation.json HTTP status: 404
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (text.js:115)
xhr.onreadystatechange @ text.js:115  this error in frontend